# Cassandra - How group by latest timestamp

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I saw some related topics here , but still it isn't clear to me,  How group by the latest row values with cassandra 4.0.1

Let's say my table looks like;

```
CREATE TABLE simple_search (
    engine text,
    term text,
    time bigint,
    rank bigint,
    url text,
    domain text,
    pagenum bigint,
    descr text,
    display_url text,
    title text,
    type text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((domain), term , time , engine, url , pagenum)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (term DESC, time DESC,  engine DESC , url DESC);
```

My data looks like:

```
SELECT time, rank, term  from search_by_domain_termsV2 where domain ='zerotoappstore.com' 



time ,    rank, term 
1633297772, 105,  avfoundation swift
1633315263, 112,  best ide
1633332881, 119,  best ide
1633365856, 50,   developing an app cost
1633375273, 36,   developing an app cost
```

I want to have after group by

```
time ,    rank, term 
1633297772, 105,  avfoundation swift
1633332881, 119,  best ide
1633375273, 36,   developing an app cost
```

If I do

```
SELECT max(time) , rank, term  from search_by_domain_termsV2 where domain ='zerotoappstore.com'  GROUP BY term;
```

it gives me the correct max time value but not correct rating,and term.

```
1633297772  105 avfoundation swift
1633332881  112 best ide
1633375273  50  developing an app cost
```

Is it possible to group by term and take the max value of time  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@VitalyT,

First, if we're not specifying the `pagenum` as part of the clustering order by clause of the create table construct, it would give you an error as follows:

```
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Clustering key columns must exactly match columns in CLUSTERING ORDER BY directive"
```

so, it has to be like as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS simple_search(
...
PRIMARY KEY (domain, term, time, engine, url, pagenum)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (term DESC, time DESC, engine DESC, url [ASC|DESC]);
```

Next, with the give data sample of 5 rows. Note, I assumed some values for `engine`, `url`, `pagenum` columns as those values weren't provided in the original question:

```
SELECT * FROM simple_search ;
 domain             | term                   | time       | engine  | url  | pagenum | descr | display_url | rank | title | type
--------------------+------------------------+------------+---------+------+---------+-------+-------------+------+-------+------
 zerotoappstore.com | developing an app cost | 1633375273 | engine5 | url5 |       5 |  null |        null |   36 |  null | null
 zerotoappstore.com | developing an app cost | 1633365856 | engine4 | url4 |       4 |  null |        null |   50 |  null | null
 zerotoappstore.com |               best ide | 1633332881 | engine3 | url3 |       3 |  null |        null |  119 |  null | null
 zerotoappstore.com |               best ide | 1633315263 | engine2 | url2 |       2 |  null |        null |  112 |  null | null
 zerotoappstore.com |     avfoundation swift | 1633297772 | engine1 | url1 |       1 |  null |        null |  105 |  null | null

(5 rows)
```

we would get the following result if we only retrieve the `MAX(time)` column (without any `GROUP BY`):

```
SELECT MAX(time),rank,term FROM simple_search WHERE domain = 'zerotoappstore.com';

 system.max(time) | rank | term
------------------+------+------------------------
       1633375273 |   36 | developing an app cost

(1 rows)
```

Now, let's see what happens if we include the `GROUP BY term` clause to the same exact `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT MAX(time), rank, term FROM simple_search WHERE domain = 'zerotoappstore.com' GROUP BY term;
 system.max(time) | rank | term
------------------+------+------------------------
       1633375273 |   36 | developing an app cost
       1633332881 |  119 |               best ide
       1633297772 |  105 |     avfoundation swift

(3 rows)
```

What if we remove the `MAX` aggregate function on `time` column because we've the data already stored in the descending order for `time` column? We get the following:

```
SELECT time,rank,term FROM simple_search WHERE domain = 'zerotoappstore.com' GROUP BY term;

 time       | rank | term
------------+------+------------------------
 1633375273 |   36 | developing an app cost
 1633332881 |  119 |               best ide
 1633297772 |  105 |     avfoundation swift

(3 rows)
```

Is this what you want as your result? Please also see [the corresponding documentation](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/4.0/cassandra/cql/dml.html#group-by-clause) for certain conditions as it is laid out.